ODE book for a computer science researcher (Birkoff/Rota vs Arnold)
I've have been looking for a book on ODEs and have narrowed it down to 2 candidates: Birkoff and Rota's 'ordinary differential equations' or Arnold's 'ordinary differential equations: 3rd edition'.
From reading online and skimming the texts, it is my understanding that B&R's book teaches a traditional course on ODEs, full of all the tricks and numerical methods, whereas Arnold's book takes a less traditional geometric approach focusing less on tricks/numerical methods.
What I am unsure of is whether having a deep theoretical understanding of ODEs is more important when applying differential equations, or if learning a more traditional tricks/numerical approach is better.
Currently I'm leaning more towards the side of Arnold's approach, as I can't help but feel that if differential equations were needed there would exist many programs/packages for numerical procedures making them less important for me to learn. However, other comments on questions such as this make me think going the traditional route would be the safer option.
I would appreciate any suggestions as to which approach would be better in my circumstances.
edit:
To clarify my intentions for reading this book , I will be immediately using it as a prerequisite it to the theoretical book John Lee's Smooth Manifolds after which point I will be reading a book on dynamical systems (which will obviously also use ODE's). However, as mentioned in the question title, my primary interest is within computer science so when choosing these texts I like to consider which may be best applicable (as most texts seem to provide adequate prerequisites for later texts).

Why not both? ${}$

Possibly. However this book is partly in preparation for a course on dynamical systems. So i would like to go though ODEs relatively quickly before then (so a single book would be the preferable option).

Why not just go through a book on dynamical systems like Strogatz?

Apologies, I was mixed up in the previous reply. I'm actually primarily in need of this book as a prerequisite for John Lee's Introduction To Smooth Manifolds that will then be followed by a course on dynamical systems (for which I had intended to read a book like Strogatz or Wiggins separately for dynamical systems). While either book I believe will suffice as a prerequisite I thought i might as well get the best foundation for later books.

Please add these important points of motivation directly to your question text, as that slightly modifies the direction of the question and the answers you need. The question has some impetus towards numerical analysis, while the comment makes clear that you want to avoid to go too far into that topic and stay clearly on the theoretical side.

Numerical techniques are best learned after you have a solid foundation on the theory of differential equations. Very few of the theorems and tools of numerical ODEs apply in any meaningful way to the general theory of ODEs. Given that you are learning this as a prerequisite for a more theoretical book, I would recommend sticking to a more theoretical treatment of the subject then go into numerics later if you want. That being said, Arnold is still a bit nonstandard even amongst other ODE texts. As for recommendations, I would recommend Teschl and Hirsch & Smale from the linked post, or other books such as Hale or Perko depending on your taste.
I will also like to comment on this statement

[...] I can't help but feel that if differential equations were needed there would exist many programs/packages for numerical procedures making them less important for me to learn.

If you do end up in some application that requires the numerical solution of ODEs, it really does pay to know some of the basic theoretical properties of various methods implemented in software and how they fit with your problem. There are no one-size-fits-all algorithms for the numerical solution of ODEs and there are many properties of the ODE system (size, stiffness, sparsity, computational expense of function evaluation) that must match up well with properties of specific algorithms (convergence order, explicit vs. implicit, fixed vs. adaptive time stepping, number of function evaluations). Default ODE solvers in environments like MATLAB or SciPy tend to work well on a wide variety of small problems, but I have personally seen certain projects deemed as infeasible because of the speed of these specific solvers when swapping algorithms results speedups of several orders of magnitude. The two books by Hairer, Norsett, and Wanner are a standard and thorough introduction to the theory of numerical ODEs and many of the methods introduced in these texts are the basis for algorithms used widely in applications.

What would you say is most non-standard about Arnold's book? (I had considered it mainly due to the fact that on questions asking what ODE book to read, many comments seemed to always recommend Arnold's).

I think the geometric flavor is less typical. It ends up covering much of the same material as the references I mentioned so it is a fine reference.

The relation to numerical methods is nicely treated in the other answer by whpowell96.
What you really need to start your study plan (from your comment) is the existence theory and the smooth dependence on parameters (which include the initial point). This is a rather compact part that can be found in all books, even the Hairer one.
The remainder of the contents of the theory books is usually filled with some classes of solvable and semi-solvable ODE problems (and the tricks and methods to solve them) that are important for motivation or the development of further theories.  Among them:

Some isolated first-order types (that Rota has strong opinions on) that have their main use as non-trivial test cases.
The important class of linear systems with constant coefficients. Local linearizations are generally the tool for the efficient application of numerical methods (see Newton method) and the local analysis of interesting points like stationary ones. Relates to the eigen decomposition and may include an introduction to the Laplace transform.
General linear systems and linear equations of higher order. Has some simplification in the existence theory and structure in the solution space. There are some methods that provide some limited simplifications.
Sturm-Liouville boundary value problems as entry to PDE and the application of harmonic analysis. Named normal forms for some classes of linear second order equations.
Perturbation methods, regular and singular.
Regular singular points as initial state or boundary point, behavior at infinity.

All these additional points and more are useful somewhere, but not necessary for the immediate goal to study curves like geodesics or integral curves of vector fields on smooth manifolds. Some you will need in the study of dynamical systems.
